# Target background-image (url) in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm curious if I can use CSS to target the first url syntax below if a user is below a certain screen width.

For example, if a user's browsers is below 700px, I do not want to show the first background image (background.png) - just the second (background1.jpg).

```
<div class="right-header" style="background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/background.png'), url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/background1.jpg');">
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use media queries for that:

In your CSS file:

```
.right-header {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/background.jpg');
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .right-header {
      background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/background1.jpg');
  }
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="right-header"></div>
```

Comment: By the way, in your code, you are using an inline CSS, is highly recommended to use an external CSS file, link it with the `link` HTML tag.